# Django upload file : test request == POST or use decorator?

Tags: python, django

I've just read this in the django doc :

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST

In the example given they do like that :

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
```

I've just read before that we can use some decorator of django like :

```
@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def my_view(request):
    # I can assume now that only GET or POST requests make it this far
```

Even one called `@require_post()`.

It's a question about syntax and I want to know :

1. if I use decorator, it will stop the function before its execution if i'm not requesting by POST ?
2. If 1) is True, isn't the decorators option much 'python cool' ?

Thanks in advance.

Besta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The decorators in django.views.decorators.http can be used to restrict access to views based on the request method. These decorators will return a django.http.HttpResponseNotAllowed if the conditions are not met.

[View decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/decorators/)

As for 2, `if request.method == 'POST'` is perfectly fine and used in function based views.

Comment: so there isn't a prefered way to do in that case?

Comment: I'd say that restricing access for specific request types is only useful for designing a web API, where you cannot expect what method will be used. Normally, since files are involved, you'd only expect a POST request so one could argue that even the if condition is superfluous.